# Unselect all options from multiple select

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have following **multiple select**:

```
<div class="wide block text-center">
        <span
            x-show="modifierError"
            class="text-danger">Please select at least 1 attribute</span>
        <select
            x-model="selectedModifiers"
            id="selectedModifiers"
            data-field="{{ $data['field']  }}"
            data-type="select"
            class="selectize wide"
            multiple
            data-searchtext="Select Modifier(s)"
            data-searchable="true"
        >
            @foreach($data['values'] as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{ str($value)->title()->replace('_', ' ') }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

Button where the reset action is triggered on click:

```
<button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-danger"
            @click="resetModifiers()"
        >Reset</button>
```

And this is Alpine method to use it:

```
Alpine.data("filter", (data) => ({
        filterValues: {},
        filteredValues: {},
        orderByClass: {},
        orderByValue: {},
        selectedModifiers: {},
        sheetModifierMinimum: 0,
        sheetModifierMaximum: 10,
        modifierError: false,
        data,

        resetModifiers()
            {
            if(typeof this.selectedModifiers.length === "undefined" ||    
                this.selectedModifiers.length === 0)
                {
                   return;
                }

               delete this.filteredValues['sheetModifiers']

               this.selectedModifiers = {}

               search(this.data.filterLink, this.filteredValues)
        }, ......
```

Is it possible to remove all selected options?

Answer (score 0):

The `selectedModifiers` should be an array since it will contain multiple values. At the reset function, you can reset its value by `this.selectedModifiers = []`:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div class="wide block text-center" x-data="filter">
        <select
            x-model="selectedModifiers"
            id="selectedModifiers"
            class="selectize wide"
            multiple
            data-searchtext="Select Modifier(s)"
            data-searchable="true"
        >
            <option value="1">Modifier #1</option>
            <option value="2">Modifier #2</option>
            <option value="3">Modifier #3</option>
        </select>
        
<button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-outline-danger"
            @click="resetModifiers()"
        >Reset</button>   
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
Alpine.data("filter", (data) => ({
        selectedModifiers: [],
        data,

        resetModifiers() {
           this.selectedModifiers = []
        },
}))
})
</script>
```